# How to add Id to Radio button in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to add Unique ID to my Radio button. My code is written in foreach loop. As it is generating same name and Id for all same buttons, but I want same name but Id should be different. Where should I add Id ?? Help please. My code is mentioned below:

```
 <fieldset class="TimeSection">
    <legend class="accessibleText"> <%= Resources.ChooseTime%> </legend>  
        <% var count = 0;%>
        <% foreach (var slot in Model.Slots)
           { %>
        <% if (count < 5)
           { %>
        <span>          
            <%=Html.RadioButton(model => model.Arrangement,slot.Number, slot.Available == false ? new { disabled = "disabled" } : null)%>

            <span <% if (!slot.Available){ %> class="disabled" <% } %>>
                <%= slot.SlotTime%></span>
            <% if (slot.Number == Model.ArrivalTimeslot)
               { %>
            <input type="hidden" name="ExistingTimeslot" value="<%=slot.Number%>" />
            <% } %>
        </span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <% } %>
        <% count = count + 1; %>
        <% } %>  
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Show us your `foreach` code as well.

Comment: Declare a variable `int i = 0` outside your foreach, then instead of `Id = "SlotID"` have `Id = String.Format("SlotID{0}", i.ToString())`. After that increment `i++` before the end of foreach. This will give you ids like SlotID0, SlotID1... etc.,

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. I am waiting for your answer. I have not used  Id="SlotId" in Htmlbutton code.

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem? One more point, you need to have id in the else part of `slot.Available == false` as well. Let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%=Html.RadioButton(model => model.Arrangement,slot.Number, slot.Available == false ? new { disabled = "disabled" } : null)%>`

should be -

`<%=Html.RadioButton(model => model.Arrangement,slot.Number, slot.Available == false ? (object)new { disabled = "disabled", id = String.Format("SlotID{0}", count.ToString()) } : new { id = String.Format("SlotID{0}", count.ToString()) })%>`

**Key Point** is to have `id = String.Format("SlotID{0}", count.ToString())`

Comment: I tried your solution, but getting error "Type of Conditional Expression can not be determined". And one more thing How we can handle 'null' case if slot.Available == false get false.

Comment: Let me ask you this question, without my proposed code, does your code runs and renders? If you dont have working code, then please correct your code and then apply the solution I proposed.

Comment: Yes dude. I have executable code. As you suggested to write Id in new section twice in Conditional operator, when I remove last one and replace with null it does not show error but I also need Id in false state. So how we can handle it.

Comment: Ok, try by adding `(object)` to the first the section of html attributes. I updated my answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, Thats I want. Thank you so much..Now its working fine. Now Genious! ..I want one more help from your side. I want to use this "id" to show in label for as Code is   <label for="<%=id%>"> 
                                       </label> but it is not working. Can you assist me to right exact syntax. Once again I appreciate your help.  :)

Comment: I want to access this id in Label for tag. So how we can do it?

Comment: Try this - `<label for="<%=String.Format("SlotID{0}", count.ToString())%>">`

Comment: Ok. It worked. Many Thanks:) Can I have your Email Id?

Comment: If you are done with this question, please close the question by marking it as answer. For any additional question, please post them in Stackoverflow and there are many expert people who can answer your questions. I may not be able to share my email on public forum. You can have my Twitter Handle - http://twitter.com/RamiRamilu